# SUM a calculated value based on ID

Tags: sql

So i have something like this:

```
SELECT WB.ID,
((WB.DUR+WB.DUR)*((coalesce(t.total,0)) + (coalesce(tx.total,0)))/(DURA.TOTDUR+DISTA.TOTDIST)) as X,
...
...
...
```

I'm trying to get the X summed based on WB.ID

DURA and DISTA are both joined and are not db tables(local). same goes to t and tx

```
ID  X
25  2127.480000
26  6.200000
32  47.120000
33  0.360000
33  1.550000
33  0.240000
42  49.590000
44  21.850000
52  162.670000
```

RESULT:

```
ID  X           SUM(X)
25  2127.480000 2127.480000
26  6.200000    6.200000
32  47.120000   47.120000
33  0.360000    2.150000
33  1.550000    2.150000
33  0.240000    2.150000
42  49.590000   49.590000
44  21.850000   21.850000
52  162.670000  162.670000
```

Comment: Please provide sample data and the exact problem your are facing.

Comment: Added sample data. I just cant figure out how to make it sum

Comment: @Tiriii . . . The two columns are the same in the sampled data, so I don't understand the question.

Answer (score 0):

From the sample data, this looks like a simple sum using a window function:

```
select id, 
       x, 
       sum(x) over (partition by id) as sum_x
from the_table
order by id;
```

If `x` is the result of another query, use a derived table:

```
select id, x, 
       sum(x) over (partition by id) as sum_x
from (
  select ...., 
         ... as x
  from ...
) t
order by id;
```